# PHP script times out earlier than max_execution_time

Tags: php, timeout, execution

I am testing a page generated by a script that performs some operations and redirects to another script. It times out at ~ 60 seconds although the max_execution_time is set to 300.

Other revelant settings could be:

```
mysql.connect_timeout   60
default_socket_timeout  60
```

Would these be causing this behavior?

Comment: If its the *page* that shows a timeout, perhaps "504 Gateway Time-out", then the PHP script might still be running. See other settings in Apache (not PHP related).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP did you use the function

- [PHP manual set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: FYI - this command is analogous to setting `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`, which the OP has already done.

Comment: `max_execution_time` is a php.ini directive as you said, but I suggest to try the `set_time_limit()` at the top of the PHP script to ensure there is no configuration issue.

Comment: Sure, well a check of `phpinfo()` would verify whether or not `max_execution_time` is being set correctly by the `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that your PHP configuration could be overriding it. For example, I once had set `php_value max_execution_time 600` in my Apache VirtualHost configuration on the `<Directory>` of my Drupal 5 install, but a file in Drupal 5 core has a line that containss `max_execution_time 240`. Because the Drupal code was processed later, it overrode the Apache configuration option.

The solution for me to "force" my declaration was to set it in Apache as `php_admin_value max_execution_time 600`. The `php_admin_value` means that PHP scripts cannot change the value you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly hitting the `memory_limit` set in `php.ini`? Run `top` while the script is running and see if its memory consumption increases to near the set limit before timing out.

I would highly doubt that the current settings for `mysql.connect_timeout` and `default_socket_timeout` would be causing any problems.

Also, just to make sure, you did restart apache after making the `php.ini` changes, correct?

Answer (score 0):

This could have been re-configured in a .htaccess file somewhere within the site (or superior folders).